# How to get the catcode of a token?

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

For debugging a complicated macro I would like to print out the catcode of a token.  Optimally I would like to have a macro `\getcatcode` such that, for example, `\getcatcode{a}` would expand to `10`.  How can this be done?

I found lots of information about how to set/change catcodes, but nothing about how to read them.

Comment: BTW: the catcode of `a` is 11 (letter) not 10 (space).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `\catcode` together with `\the` to get the catcode of the token:

```
\the\catcode`a
```

Note: The `` ` `` turns the next character into its ASCII number which is 
required for `\catcode`.

As custom macro:

```
\newcommand{\getcatcode}[1]{\the\catcode`#1}
```

Special characters must be escaped with a backslash, e.g. `%` must be written as `\%`, `#` as `\#` etc. It doesn't hurt to write normal letters the same way, e.g. `\getcatcode\a` works as well.

Answer (score 17):

As explained in an exercise of the TeXbook one can also write

```
\newcommand{\printcatcode}[1]{%
   \ifcase\catcode`#1\relax
      escape\or
      beginning of group\or
      end of group\or
      math shift\or
      tab\or
      end of line\or
      parameter\or
      superscript\or
      subscript\or
      ignored\or
      space\or
      letter\or
      otherchar\or
      active\or
      comment\or
      ignored\fi}

 The category code is `\printcatcode\%'
```

Just to point out that any of the "code tables" in TeX can be used to access the value (`\catcode`, `\lccode`, `\uccode`, `\mathcode`, `\delcode`, `\sfcode`).

Answer (score 8):

The solutions offered by Martin and egreg print the *current* catcode of a character. I understood the original question to be how one can print the catcode of a *token*, i.e., one that has already been scanned, possibly in the past, when different catcodes were in effect. Consider this:

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newcommand{\x}{@}
\catcode`\@=12
\newcommand{\y}{@}

\newcommand{\printcatcode}[1]{
  \def\aux##1{
     \message{The catcode of the ##1 in \noexpand#1 is \getcatcode{##1}.^^J}
  }
  \expandafter\aux#1
}

\printcatcode{\x}
\printcatcode{\y}
```

Clearly the `@`s stored in the macros `\x` and `\y` have two different catcodes. However, with Martin's macro, we get:

```
The catcode of the @ in \x  is 12.
The catcode of the @ in \y  is 12.
```

That is because Martin's macro prints the 'current' catcode of the character represented by the token, rather than the catcode actually stored in the token.

The following is a better solution:

```
\begingroup%
  % locally ensure that characters have their expected catcodes
  \catcode`\$=3%
  \catcode`\&=4%
  \catcode`\#=6%
  \catcode`\^=7%
  \catcode`\_=8%
  \catcode`\ =10%
  \catcode`\a=11%
  \catcode`\+=12%
  \catcode`\~=13%
  \gdef\getcatcode#1{%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1$3\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1&4\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1##6\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1^7\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1_8\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1 10\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1a11\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1+12\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1\noexpand~13\else%
    \ifcat\noexpand#1\relax16\else%
      unknown%
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
  }
\endgroup
```

With this, we get the expected answer:

```
The catcode of the @ in \x  is 11.
The catcode of the @ in \y  is 12.
```

The code is a bit awkward and I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. I was unable to test for catcodes 0, 1, 2, 5, 9, 14, and 15, but I am not sure if such catcodes can actually occur after the input has been tokenized.

Comment: Category codes 1 and 2 can certainly exist: think `\def\x{{a}}` which holds three tokens, `{`, `a` and `}`.