# Output ASCII code as character on terminal in Latex?

Tags: tex-core, characters, debugging, terminal-output

If I have a letter/character, I can output its ASCII value using `\number` and  backtick command:

```
*\typeout{\number`a}
97
```

What do I do if I have "97", and I want to show "a" in terminal? I have thought of `\char` - but note that `\char` *typesets*, it doesn't output to terminal (<sub>removed `\char"97` hex usage as per comment</sub>):

```
*\typeout{\char97}
\char 97
```

What is the right command to use here?

Comment: `\char"97` doesn't give an `a` even in a document. `"91` is a hex-value, you would need either `\char"61` or `\char91`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 {\uccode`A=97
    \uppercase{\typeout{== A ==}}}
```

will typeout the character with character code 97

Comment: not catcode though :-) last time I checked TeX didn't have that many catcodes --- character code

Comment: I have written a small tool called `texref` which can give quick information about category codes and character information, and maybe other things too in future. If you think it's useful, perhaps consider including it in your answer.

https://github.com/kieranclancy/texref.git

Answer (score 5):

If you have hex value rather than the ascii code value then you can use `^^61` to represent `a`. The hex digits have to be in lowercase (for the letters a-f). If you have only the ascii code number then you have to build your own table (if you want to mix such output with other material) or use the ingenious trick with `\uccode`by David, but the latter doesn't really mix well with anything in addition. A simple way to build such a table would be

```
\makeatletter
\def\asciichar#1{\@nameuse{ascii@\number#1}}
\@namedef{ascii@97}{a}
\@namedef{ascii@98}{b} ... % and all the others
\makeatother
```

You could add some safety checks to see if the internal command is actually defined etc.